# D3 (v3.4) edge bundle chart and update button to load a new dataset

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a D3 (v3.4) edge bundling chart and I want to update the chart with a new dataset by clicking an 'update' button. I'd like to see the chart update displaying data from the data2.json (and not data1.json). I currently have an update button and the start of an updateData() function that simply reads in the new dataset, though I'm not sure what parts of my code I need to include in this function to update via transition. I'm aware that certain parts of the chart need to be re-rendered and it isn't a case of simply loading in a new dataset. I was using this [Update d3.js data with button press](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8) example as a basis though because it's a line chart the transition updates are a lot simpler and so less helpful to my edge bundle chart. My code below represents a minimal reproducible example..

**HTML/JS**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

    <style>

        .node {
            font: 300 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            fill: rgb(0, 0, 0, .6);
          }
          
          .link {
            stroke: steelblue;
            fill: none;
            pointer-events: none;
          }   
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="grid-container"></div>

        <div class="grid-item" id="chart">

            <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
                <script>

                var diameter = 760,
                    radius = diameter / 2;
                    innerRadius = radius - 160;
                
                var cluster = d3.cluster()
                    .size([360, innerRadius]);
                
                var line = d3.radialLine()
                    .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.85))
                    .radius(function(d) { return d.y; })
                    .angle(function(d) { return d.x / 180 * Math.PI; });
                
                var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", diameter)
                    .attr("height", diameter)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");
                
                var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link"),
                    node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");
                
                d3.json("data1.json", function(error, classes) {
                    if (error) throw error;
                
                    var root = packageHierarchy(classes)
                        .sum(function(d) { return d.size; });
                
                  cluster(root);
                
                  link = link
                      .data(packageImports(root.leaves()))
                      .enter().append("path")
                      .each(function(d) { d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1]; })
                      .attr("class", "link")
                      .attr("d", line);
                
                  node = node
                      .data(root.leaves())
                      .enter().append("text")
                      .attr("class", "node")
                      .attr("dy", "0.31em")
                      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y + 8) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)"); })
                      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
                      .text(function(d) { return d.data.key; })
                      .on("mouseover", mouseovered)
                      .on("mouseout", mouseouted);
                });
                
                function mouseovered(d) {
                  node
                      .each(function(n) { n.target = n.source = false; });
                
                  link
                      .classed("link--target", function(l) { if (l.target === d) return l.source.source = true; })
                      .classed("link--source", function(l) { if (l.source === d) return l.target.target = true; })
                      .filter(function(l) { return l.target === d || l.source === d; })
                      .raise();
                  node
                      .classed("node--target", function(n) { return n.target; })
                      .classed("node--source", function(n) { return n.source; });
                }
                
                function mouseouted(d) {
                  link
                      .classed("link--target", false)
                      .classed("link--source", false);
                
                  node
                      .classed("node--target", false)
                      .classed("node--source", false);
                }
                
                // Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.
                function packageHierarchy(classes) {
                  var map = {};
                
                  function find(name, data) {
                    var node = map[name], i;
                    if (!node) {
                      node = map[name] = data || {name: name, children: []};
                      if (name.length) {
                        node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
                        node.parent.children.push(node);
                        node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
                      }
                    }
                    return node;
                  }
                
                  classes.forEach(function(d) {
                    find(d.name, d);
                  });
                
                  return d3.hierarchy(map[""]);
                }
                
                // Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
                function packageImports(nodes) {
                  var map = {},
                      imports = [];
                
                  // Compute a map from name to node.
                  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    map[d.data.name] = d;
                  });
                
                  // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
                  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    if (d.data.imports) d.data.imports.forEach(function(i) {
                      imports.push(map[d.data.name].path(map[i]));
                    });
                  });
                
                  return imports;
                }

                // update data function
                function updateData() {

                  d3.json("data1.json", function(error, classes) {
                    if (error) throw error;
                
                    var root = packageHierarchy(classes)
                        .sum(function(d) { return d.size; });
                  
                    var svg = d3.select("body").transition();

                  });
                }
                </script>
                
            </div>

        </div>

</body>

  <div id="option">
    <input name="updateButton"
    type="button"
    value="Update"
    onclick="updateData()"
    />
  </div>

</html>
```

**data1.json**

```
[
    {
        "name": "flare.A.dataA",
        "imports": [
            "flare.B.dataB"

        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "flare.B.dataB",
        "imports": [
            "flare.A.dataA"
        ]
    }
]
```

**data2.json**

```
[
    {
        "name": "flare.A.newdataA",
        "imports": [
            "flare.B.newdataB"

        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "flare.B.newdataB",
        "imports": [
            "flare.A.newdataA"
        ]
    }
]
```

I can't find any examples of an edge bundle chart with an update button. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure this is a v3.4 example ?

Comment: I think so, I'm using v.34 (<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried editing your code and was able to achieve this. To update the data, we need to make use of enter, update and exit methods. In v3 I remember, when we enter the new data and this will create any missing links or nodes and using exit(), we can remove nodes, links which are not present. After enter, we append the new nodes,links and later update its attributes. We can actually use the same function to create and update which you can try. I dont know why the newDataB is not coming as node in below function. Something wrong with my sample data it seems. Your new sample data is working fine with below code.

```js
var diameter = 760,
  radius = diameter / 2;
innerRadius = radius - 160;

var cluster = d3.cluster()
  .size([360, innerRadius]);

var line = d3.radialLine()
  .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.85))
  .radius(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .angle(function(d) {
    return d.x / 180 * Math.PI;
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", diameter)
  .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link"),
  node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");

switchData(1);

function mouseovered(d) {
  node
    .each(function(n) {
      n.target = n.source = false;
    });

  link
    .classed("link--target", function(l) {
      if (l.target === d) return l.source.source = true;
    })
    .classed("link--source", function(l) {
      if (l.source === d) return l.target.target = true;
    })
    .filter(function(l) {
      return l.target === d || l.source === d;
    })
    .raise();
  node
    .classed("node--target", function(n) {
      return n.target;
    })
    .classed("node--source", function(n) {
      return n.source;
    });
}

function mouseouted(d) {
  link
    .classed("link--target", false)
    .classed("link--source", false);

  node
    .classed("node--target", false)
    .classed("node--source", false);
}

// Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.
function packageHierarchy(classes) {
  var map = {};

  function find(name, data) {
    var node = map[name],
      i;
    if (!node) {
      node = map[name] = data || {
        name: name,
        children: []
      };
      if (name.length) {
        node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
        node.parent.children.push(node);
        node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
      }
    }
    return node;
  }

  classes.forEach(function(d) {
    find(d.name, d);
  });

  return d3.hierarchy(map[""]);
}

// Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
function packageImports(nodes) {
  var map = {},
    imports = [];

  // Compute a map from name to node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    map[d.data.name] = d;
  });

  // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    if (d.data.imports) d.data.imports.forEach(function(i) {
      imports.push(map[d.data.name].path(map[i]));
    });
  });

  return imports;
}

// update data function
function updateData(classes) {

  var root = packageHierarchy(classes);

  cluster(root);

  var nodes = root.leaves();
  var links = packageImports(root.leaves());

  let link = svg.selectAll('.link').data(links);

  link.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "link").append("path").each(function(d) {
      d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1];
    });
  svg.selectAll('path').attr("class", "link").transition()
    .duration(1000).attr("d", line);
  link.exit().remove();

  let node = svg.selectAll('.node').data(nodes);
  node.enter().append('g').append("text");
  svg.selectAll('text').attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y + 8) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)");
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
    })
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("dy", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.key;
    });


  node.exit().remove();

}

function switchData(dataset) {
  let classes = [];
  if (dataset == 0) {
    classes = [{
        "name": "flare.A.newdataA",
        "size": 1000,
        "imports": [
          "flare.B.newdataB"

        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "flare.B.newdataB",
        "size": 1400,
        "imports": [
          "flare.A.newdataA"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "flare.A.newdataC",
        "size": 1200,
        "imports": [
          "flare.A.newdataA", "flare.B.newdataB"
        ]
      }
    ];


  } else

  {
    classes = [{
        "name": "flare.A.dataA",
        "size": 1000,
        "imports": [
          "flare.B.dataB"

        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "flare.B.dataB",
        "size": 1200,
        "imports": [
          "flare.A.dataA"
        ]
      }
    ];

  }

  updateData(classes)

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>

  <style>
    .node {
      font: 300 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      fill: rgb(0, 0, 0, .6);
    }
    
    .link {
      stroke: steelblue;
      fill: none;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="grid-container"></div>

  <div class="grid-item" id="chart">

    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
  </div>

  </div>


</body>


<div id="option">
  <input name="updateButton" type="button" value="Update" onclick="switchData(0)" />
</div>
<div id="option">
  <input name="updateButton" type="button" value="SwitchBack" onclick="switchData(1)" />
</div>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks very promising, I'm just testing it at the moment. Can you tell me what "size" refers to in the data themselves?

Comment: Okay. This seems to work. I have a button that changes the lines/labels (new dataset). However, If I want to get back to the original dataset with another button/function, it will only display the number of lines/labels that existed for the second dataset. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Added size as your package hierarchy function was working on sum of size. Check how are you creating root.

Comment: If you want to go back to original dataset, again use update function. I think size attribute might be messing it. Need to change packageHierarchy function if you don't want size. I will come back on this.

Comment: You are right, new links and new nodes were not getting updated. I added new statement to update all paths and nodes. https://jsfiddle.net/bandnak/3cwz2y68/159/  Also updated the above code.

Comment: In the updated code, you only need one method to create or update the edge bundle. I was earlier not updating attributes on correct nodes or links

Comment: I've accepted your answer and transferred the bounty because you (more than) answered my original question, thank you! Your code works nicely for me, but I want my data to be in an external file rather than in the js file iself. I'm struggling to replace the data with "d3.json("data1.json", function(error, classes) {if (error) throw error;"} in order to do this. Are you able to help with that? That's my last issue really. Feel free not to answer this, you've already done a lot! I appreciate it.

Comment: You might be facing CORs policy issue, can you join this chat room to discuss trivial issues. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/246044/d3-edge-bundling?tab=general

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

> ```
> transition().duration(1000)
>                 .ease("elastic")
>                 .call(draw);
> ```

from [D3 transitions on enter/update/remove](https://gist.github.com/Petrlds/4045315)

Also

[D3.js update with transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153291/d3-js-update-with-transition)

Comment: Can you explain how this fits into my updateData() function? "elastic" and "draw" aren't found anywhere else in my code.

Comment: btw I gave you the bounty since the time has elapsed and you're the only answer, enjoy!

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to recreate the issue and give complete explanation